# `C-M-SPC` is not working anymore for `mark-sexp`. It has changed to `C-M-@`. Why did that happen?

Tags: key-bindings

I have been using `mark-sexp` often because I am working with Common Lisp. Until now, the binding `C-M-SPC` has worked out pretty well.

For some reason that I do not understand, the binding has changed. Now, emacs says `mark-sexp` is bonded to `C-M-@` (which I cannot achieve using the keyboard, by the way).

This is my humble [config file](https://github.com/pdelfino/my-emacs-config/blob/main/.emacs). I am not sure why this has happened. As you see, I have not touched on this specific point.

Is this some side-effect from another modification? Why did this happen? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Not enough info. What's `C-M-x` bound to? Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. If yes, `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: `mark-sexp` is bound to both `C-M-SPC` and `C-M-@` by default. What is `C-M-SPC bound to now? (`C-h k C-M-SPC`)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, @Drew. `C-M-x` is bound to `slime-eval-defun`. If try t use `C-M-SPC` using `emacs -Q` the same problem happens!

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil'. Now, mark-sexp is bounded to  `C-M-@`. But, if I try to using it, it does not work.  The only it works is with the slow `M-x mark-sexp`.

Comment: As a temporary solution, I have bound the command `mark-sexp` to `C-M-m` and it works. But I wished I could have `C-M-SPC` back since I was already used to it and it is the default.